# rewriting url with updating url in yii2

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii2

how change this:

```
site/faq
```

to this:

```
site/faq?festival=nouroz98&id=100000&data=information
```

this is the FestivalRule class

```
class FestivalRule implements UrlRuleInterface
{
   public $pattern;
   public $route;
   public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
{
    return [$route, $params];
}

public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
{
    if(!empty($request->getQueryParams())){
        if($request->getPathInfo() == 'site/faq'){
            return  [
                'site/faq',
                $request->getQueryParams()
            ];
        }
    }else{
        return [
            'site/faq',
            [
                'festival' => 'nouroze99',
                'id' => '10000',
                'data' => 'from db',
            ]
        ];

    }
    return false;
}
 }
```

this is the urlmanager config:

```
 'rules' => [
             [
        'class' => 'app\components\FestivalRule',
        'pattern' => 'site/faq/<festival:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<data:\w+>', 
         'route' => 'site/faq',
         ],
```

I want if the URL requested without any parameters i changing that with parameters but i can't place the parameters in URL.

> all parameters sent but i wanted url changes too (parameters shows in URL)!

Comment: You should take a look at documentation and existing implementations ( https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlruleinterface and https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlrule ) - your `FestivalRule` does not make any sense. `createUrl()` should return URL (as string) or false, not array. Calling it in `parseRequest()` is incorrect.

Comment: @rob006 you're right! question updated i don't use `createUrl` either but the problem exist. i pass the parameters to view but i want to show them in URL like `site/faq?festival=nouroz99&id=1000&data=from+db` or `site/faq/nouroz99/1000/from+db`